# Can we submit an html post form in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-linking

I have a question if we can submit an html post form with Linking in react-native. If yes how we can submit it?

I want to submit it to default browser (not with webview) and here is html form:

```
<form method="POST" target="..." id="..." :action="videoConferenceUrl">
      <input type="hidden" name="target" value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="requestOrigin" value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="username" :value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="password" :value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="eventID" :value="..."/>
</form>
```

Please write every way how we can submit that form in the default browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "submit it to default browser" do you mean submit the data to a server, and then on the device you open the default browser app and view the response from the server?

Comment: @alexanderbird no I only want the relevant of onPress={() => (<WebView source={{html: `<form method="POST" target="..." id="..." :action="videoConferenceUrl">
      <input type="hidden" name="target" value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="requestOrigin" value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="username" :value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="password" :value="..."/>
      <input type="hidden" name="eventID" :value="..."/>
</form>`}}>)}
This will open the webview but I want to do this in the default browser

Comment: I tried with Linking.openUrl() but I didn't work

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking, sorry! It's been a while since I've done mobile dev with react native though, so I'm probably not the right person to answer your question.

Comment: @alexanderbird I asked about making a POST FORM with Linking.openUrl. The form is in the question code.